# Создание коллекции по доступу к элементу которой вызывается функция

Tags: функции, kotlin, coroutine

Есть suspend функции возвращающие классы, реализующие интерфейс к примеру JSONConvertable. Пример функции:

```
suspend fun loadCompetitionByShortName(shortName: String = "SA")
        : Competition {
    val requestUrl = "/v2/competitions/$shortName"
    return loadObject(requestUrl)
}
```

Нужно создать коллекцию по доступу к элементу которой должна вызываться функция.
К примеру как создать такую коллекцию и вызывать её элементы я понимаю, но с не suspend функциями и возвращающими Unit:

```
    fun sayHello()
        = println("HI")

    val collection = arrayOf({sayHello()})
    collection[0]()
```

Ну и вот вопрос: как создать такую коллекцию для приведенного выше типа функций и возможно ли это? Создание и вызов элементов коллекции предполагается вне coroutine scope. К примеру такой код возвращает Job, а мне нужно возвращение объекта реализующего интерфейс:

```
    val collection:MutableList<() -> JSONConvertable> = mutableListOf()
    collection.add(
        { GlobalScope.launch { 
            ftblDtRqst.loadCompetitionByShortName("SA") as JSONConvertable
        } }
    )
```

`val obj = collection[0]()` - вот что нужно получить в итоге.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job не возвращает результат. Нужно использовать coroutine , которая будет возвращать результат. Один из способов решения данной проблемы является использования runBlocking{}.
Отредактированная функция имеет вид:

```
    val collection:MutableList<() -> JSONConvertable> = mutableListOf()
    runBlocking {
        collection.add(
            {
                runBlocking {
                     ftblDtRqst.loadCompetitionByShortName("SA") as JSONConvertable
                }
            }
        )

        val competition = requiredDataList[0]()
        println(competition)
    }
```